# Stop regex selecting first character after match

Tags: regex, perl, csv, delimiter

I have a csv in the following format;

```
"12345"|"ABC"|"ABC"[tab delimeter]
"12345"|"ABC"|"ABC"[tab delimeter]
"12345"|"ABC"|"ABC"[tab delimeter]
```

However, tabs also appear in the text, I need to remove the tabs which are not preceeded by a " .

I have the following regex which highlights the tabs which are not followed by a "
    `\t[^\"]`
but this highlights the character after the tab as well, I would like to only select and remove the tab.

**Note:** Not sure if this matters but i am running the command in TextPad before I run it in Perl.

**EDIT** test data http://pastebin.com/dYfrcSPc

Comment: So there are tabs and newlines?

Comment: Why not use a csv parser, http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/Parse-CSV-2.00/lib/Parse/CSV.pm

Comment: do you need to remove tabs that are not *directly* followed by a quote, directly preceded by a quote, or tabs that are not inside quotes?

Comment: @TomFenech No newlines, just tabs.

Comment: @M42 this is on a client machine so no downloads and no passing files through the web

Comment: @Robin I need to remove tabs which are in the text, not at the end of a line. The reason I say not followed by a double quote is that teh end line ones are all followed by a double quote.

Comment: Quoted delimiters are valid in CSV, and by applying a regex you might break your format. The safest option would be to parse the fields, remove tabs from the fields, and then reassemble the CSV lines.

Comment: And also, why not provide some proper test data for us to work with?

Comment: @Intern87 There is no point in using pastebin for that, add the code to your question and use the code formatting. Also, is that your input? Is it tab delimited, or is it `|` delimited? Are those balanced quotes? You cannot use character classes in `tr///`, but you can use ranges.

Comment: Row delimeter is Tab{t} and column delimeter is Vertical bar{|} Text Qualifyer is "

Answer (score 1):

Use this one:

```
\t(?!")
```

It means a `tab` character that is not followed by a `"` character.

Comment: I get an error when I put this into my Perl, it throws a sytax error near $string = s/\"  (full string) `$string =~ s/\t(?!")/g;`

Comment: Correct syntax is `s/regex/replace/g`. It means you are missing another `/` before the `g`

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot download a proper CSV module such as [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text%3a%3aCSV), you can use a lightweight alternative that is part of the core: [`Text::ParseWords`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text%3a%3aParseWords):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::ParseWords;

while (<DATA>) {
    my @list = quotewords('\t', 1, $_);
    tr/\t//d for @list;
    print join "\t", @list;
}

__DATA__
"12345"|"ABC    "|"ABC" next field
"12345"|"ABC"|" ABC"    next field
"123    45"|"ABC"|"ABC" next field
```

(Note: Tab characters might have been destroyed by stackoverflow formatting)

This will parse the lines and ignore quoted tabs. We can then simply remove them and put the line back together.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the easiest way would be using negative lookbehind...

```
s/(?<!")\t//g;
```

... as it'll match only those `tab` characters not *preceded* by `"` character. But if your perl doesn't support it, don't worry - there's another way:

```
s/([^"])\t/$1/g;
```

... that is, replacing any non-`"` symbol followed by `\t` with that symbol alone.